# stack level too deep (SystemStackError) when recursing

Tags: ruby

I want to make this simple calculation but it complains that the the stack isn't deep enough even for very small numbers for `n` such as 4. Other SO posts for similar topics recommend tail recursion but that isn't applicable here since you only add to an accumlated value when you reach the base case.

```
RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile_option = {
:tailcall_optimization => true,
:trace_instruction => false
}

def recursively_count_paths(x , y, n)
 if x == n &&  y == n
  return 1
  puts " we got a path people"
 elif x == n
  puts "x is done"
  return recursively_count_paths(x, y + 1, n)
 elif y == n
  puts "y is done"
  return recursively_count_paths(x + 1, y, n)
 else
 return (recursively_count_paths(x + 1, y, n) + 
recursively_count_paths(x, y + 1, n))
 end  
end

recursively_count_paths(0, 0, 20)
```

am I not supposed to return in other cases?

Comment: `puts` will never execute in the first `if` condition

Comment: @Ruslan true. but that is orthogonal to the question.

Comment: elsif rather than elif?  I'm not running this on a RubyVM, so I'm not sure this makes a difference

Comment: @MickeySheu yes!

Comment: If you're doing pathfinding, there's a number of algorithms that are proven to work and don't involve blowing your stack limit. I think this one you're using duplicates a lot of work, as well, it's very wasteful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tail recursion  isn't relevant in this case. Since you call the method recursively several times, the compiler can't make that optimization. Most of those calls are unnecessary. I was able to rewrite your code to:

```
def recursively_count_paths(x, y, n)
  return 0 if x > n or y > n
  return 1 if x == n &&  y == n
  return recursively_count_paths(x+1, y, n) + recursively_count_paths(x, y+1, n)
end
```

The first line looks for paths that are out of bounds and doesn't count those. The second line is equivalent to your first `if` statement. It returns 1 if a path has been completed. The final line is the same as your final `return` statement and simply adds all the paths going north with all the paths going east. Since we call `recursively_count_paths` twice, tail-call optimization still won't help.

If you run it using n=20, you might notice it takes awhile. This is because this algorithm takes exponentially longer as the size of the grid increases. That's because you count the same subpaths over and over again. It's also Project Euler [Problem 15](https://projecteuler.net/problem=15), so I won't provide my solution here. I will give you a hint, however: save your work.

Comment: Yes i was solving that problem. I remembered that there was a relation between that and Pascal's' triangle and I ended up devising aO(n^2) solution, thank God!